custom li css for mail
I'm trying to design a mailchimp agenda template for someone else that don't have experience in coding. So I need to apply general css in style balise so he can manipulate the content in the text editor (I need to keep also the html format list ul > li).
I would like to have list with each li with a border-bottom and a nice padding between each element of the list. This is what I get from the mailchimp editor.

It's working almost fine on my Mail app but not in Gmail who seems to ignore all basics li styles.
ul li{ 
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

ul li {
 margin-bottom: 8px !important;
 padding-bottom: 7px !important;
}

I tried to work with flex on the ul but gmail seems to ignore flex-direction too. Is there any trick that could make my list look like the image in gmail ? Or is it too complicated for css mail ?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

usally, going back to html 4.01 and inline style works fine :(

How are you including that CSS? External files won't work on some email clients.

Basically mailchimp use kind of a markdown editor where you can see and modify the html transcription on clicking on a button. The thing is that I need my client to still be able to edit the list on his own in the text editor without touching code. That's why I inject the css on a style balise at the beginning of the html template page.
